# keras always predict in a straight line

Tags: python, pandas, keras

I'm starting with deep learning. I'm trying to learn a quadratic function with a multi-layer model. The `predicted_y` seems to always be a line (build of the learnX), What am I doing wrong in here?

I hope that the code makes it clear. This is my Jupiterlab cell code:

```
import pandas as pd
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Activation
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

def my_build_model(X, y):
    model = Sequential([
        Dense(16, input_shape=(X.shape[1],)),
        Activation('relu'),
        Dense(8),
        Activation('relu'),
        Dense(4),
        Activation('relu'),
        Dense(1),
    ])

    model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer='adam', metrics=['mse'])

    model.fit(X, y, epochs=100)

    _, accuracy = model.evaluate(X, y)
    print('Accuracy: %.2f' % (accuracy*100))

    return model

n_rows = 20
X=pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [1 + x for x in range(-n_rows, 5+n_rows)],
    'b': [2 + x for x in range(-n_rows, 5+n_rows)],
    'c': [3 + x for x in range(-n_rows, 5+n_rows)],
    'd': [4 + x for x in range(-n_rows, 5+n_rows)],
    'e': [5 + x for x in range(-n_rows, 5+n_rows)],
    'f': [6 + x for x in range(-n_rows, 5+n_rows)],
})
y=pd.Series([10 + random.random() + x * x for x in range(-n_rows, 5+n_rows)])

csX = MinMaxScaler()
XContinuous = csX.fit_transform(X)

model = my_build_model(X=XContinuous, y=y)

df = pd.DataFrame({'y': y, 'predict_y': [x for [x] in model.predict(XContinuous)]})

df['y'].plot(c='#ff0000aa', label='y', legend=True)
plt.show()

df['predict_y'].plot(c='#00bb00aa', label='predict_y', legend=True)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be attributed to a couple of things.

- First of all I think you should rethink your 'randomness' of your features. If I look at `XContinuous`, all features are the same across every row.
- You might be underestimating the amount of neurons needed to approximate your function. More info [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/375655/feasibility-of-a-neural-network-fitting-a-specific-multivariate-quadratic-functi/375658#375658).

I was however able to manage a good result with some tweaks:

- randomise `X`
- `optimizer=Adam(lr=0.0001)`
- `epochs=1000`
- architecture of 10000x100x10000x100x1 dense relu's

```
Epoch 1000/1000
45/45 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 4.1500 - mean_squared_error: 4.1500
```

[image: plot y]
[image: plot y_predict]

I'm sure there are a lot better ways to do this though; the current setup feels like a huge overkill.

Is there a reason you are trying to do this with a neural network? Did you consider [`sklearn`'s linear regressors](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html)?